# What would be a good way for referring to the property of being a Home/Visitor Team?

Tags: sports

Is there a word to define the property of being the Home Team? In Brazil we say that the Home Team has the "Mando de Campo" which means "Field Ownership", as in the Home Team HAS the Field Ownership as the Visitor Team does not, I don't know if that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One phrase often used for the home team is that they have the *home field advantage* (in the US) or *home advantage* (in the UK). This refers to the psychological [advantage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_advantage) teams have when they play at home:

> In team sports, the term home advantage (also called home field/court/diamond/ice advantage) describes the advantage–usually a psychological advantage–that the home team is said to have over the visiting team as a result of playing in familiar facilities and in front of supportive fans.

Though it is used more for psychological, it is also often used to describe "what" one team has that the other does not. So the home team *has* this advantage; the visiting (or away) team does not.

This [translation site](http://www.proz.com/kudoz/portuguese_to_english/sports_fitness_recreation/3171410-mando_de_campo.html) says that *home field advantage* is the translation for the phrase *mando de campo*.

Comment: I was looking for a more neutral way of saying that, but it seems this is the only way. i didnt find anything diffrent.

Comment: What do you mean by "neutral"?

Comment: Nevermind, i didnt express myself very well. English is my second language.

Comment: I'd love to help if I can--are you saying you'd like to convey a particular tone?

Comment: No really, dont worry home field advantage will work fine.

Comment: In UK English I think we'd expect it to be `home advantage` - no field required.

Answer (score 2):

Although I cannot think of a term apart from "home team" to describe that property, the phrase "[home advantage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_advantage)" (or alternatively, *home-field advantage*) is fairly common in America. Wikipedia describes it thusly:

> [T]he advantage–usually a psychological advantage–that the home team
>   is said to have over the visiting team as a result of playing in
>   familiar facilities and in front of supportive fans.

Answer (score 2):

The home team is sometimes referred to as the HOSTS. The visiting team, as VISITORS or GUESTS.